# How do I add a help_text to a ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-forms

I know how to add a 'class' or other widget attribute to an automatically built ModelForm:

```
class ExampleSettingForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleSettingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['example_field'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'css_class' 
    class Meta:
        model = Example
```

How do I insert a **help_text=** into the example_field `Field`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Django 1.6: You can edit it within the `Meta` class. Try:

```
class ExampleSettingForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleSettingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['example_field'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'css_class' 
    class Meta:
        model = Example
        help_texts = {
                'example_field': ('Here is some help'),
        }
```

Docs on this are at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields.  See release notes at http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releases/1.6.html .  You can set your own `label`, `help_text` and `error_messages`.

Comment: I want to tack on a comment because of an issue that drove me crazy when I first started playing with ModelForms. The docs don't clarify where that underscore comes from when they introduce this concept. That underscore on `-('Here is some help')` comes from `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`

Comment: @souldeux Thanks for adding the clarification! I removed the `_` as some people won't be importing it, and those who are likely already know how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did in Django 1.9:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('__all__')
        help_texts = {
            "my_field": "This is case sensitive..."
        }
```